# Convert Decimal List to string separated by delimiter(',')

Tags: c#, string, generics

I have `IList<Decimal>` which i want to convert to string separated by ,.

I tried. `mrps` in list of decimal

```
var mrpstring = string.Join<string>(",", mrps.Cast<string>().ToList());
```

Throwing exception of Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'

Any solutions?

Comment: Try: var mrpstring = string.Join<string>(",", Convert.ToString(mrps).ToList());

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanx will take care in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Select` instead:

```
mrps.Select(d => d.ToString())
```

A `double`, as stated in the error, can't actually be `cast` to a `string`. So, the full code might look like this:

```
var mrpstring = string.Join(",", mrps.Select(d => d.ToString()).ToList());
```

Answer (score 6):

[`string.Join<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will automatically call `ToString` on each element of the `IEnumerable<T>` parameter, and there's no need to call `ToList`. So this should work:

```
var mrpstring = string.Join(",", mrps);
```

Comment: doesn't work for all cultures because it implicitly uses ToString of each value in the IEnumerable and formats the decimal to whatever culture specific format, e.g. '0.1 gets "0,1'

Comment: @MichaC It's not at all clear that that's a requirement. It may well be that OP knows exactly what culture this application will be run under and and it is not a concern. It's also likely that OP is just starting out in learning C#, and this is a practice program, so OP may not need to bother with localization at this point.

Comment: And the easiest solution is the best? ;) Decimal string formatting is a common issue, so you should always take care of it...

Comment: @MichaC In a production environment, sure. In fact I will sometimes bring up this kind of issue during interviews, just to make sure candidates are aware of it. It's worthwhile to point out, but it doesn't appear to be central to this question.

Answer (score 3):

use select and join

```
var result = string.Join(",", mrps.Select(p => p.ToString()));
```

Remember that the .ToString() method uses the `CurrentCulture` to format the string. In Germany for example this will put a comma as decimal sign and the result will be `0,01,0,02`...

use to make sure you always have the dot.

```
var result = string.Join(",", mrps.Select(p => p.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

Comment: Upvote due to the `InvariantCulture` option. Be careful out there with the decimal delimiters depending on your actual Culture!

Answer (score 3):

Casting is not the right way to convert from `decimal` to `string`, `ToString()` is. As [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) already has an overload that takes `IEnumerable<T>` and uses `ToString()`, you can pass your `IList<decimal>` in directly:

```
var mrpstring = string.Join(",", mrps);
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `mrps` is a list of double, not a list of string. So make sure that you are casting to the correct type:

```
var mrpstring = string.Join<string>(
    ",", 
    mrps.Cast<double>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `Select`:

```
string.Join(",", mrps.Select(d => d.ToString()).ToArray());
```